# Angularfire | ng deploy | Cannot read property 'printf' of undefined

Tags: angularfire2

I have a problem when I try to run `ng deploy` on a recently created Angular project. The version I'm using is 9.1.6 (I just upgraded from 9.1.5, where I got the same error). `ng serve` works probably.

```
(base) paul@Pauls-MacBook-Pro must-have % ng deploy              
 Building "must-have"
Another process, with id 4426, is currently running ngcc.
Waiting up to 250s for it to finish.
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
ES5 bundle generation complete.

chunk {0} runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime-es5.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js (polyfills) 36.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills-es5.9e286f6d9247438cbb02.js (polyfills-es5) 129 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es2015.658a3e52de1922463b54.js (main) 467 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es5.658a3e52de1922463b54.js (main) 545 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.c86817c326e37bf011e3.css (styles) 62 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-05-16T16:06:16.041Z - Hash: a4ca944a427d0323601e - Time: 68781ms


Cannot read property 'printf' of undefined
(base) paul@Pauls-MacBook-Pro must-have %
```

My versions:

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.6
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.6
@angular/cdk                      9.2.3
@angular/cli                      9.1.6
@angular/fire                     6.0.0
@angular/material                 9.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.6
@schematics/angular               9.1.6
@schematics/update                0.901.6
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

Comment: I solved it by creating a new project and only copying the `src` folder from the old to the new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is available in version 6.0.0-rc.2 of @angular/fire. Upgrade to 6.0.0-rc.2 by

```
ng add @angular/fire@next
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and every ng add @angular/fire@next did not help.

I am using angular8, angular fire and firebase hosting. So, I build the project using **ng build**, and then deployed on firebase hosting using **firebase deploy**.